# eBay Dynamic Categories for specified store id sample source code

Tags: web-services, ebay-api

I'm newbie on eBay webservice. After analysing the eBay web service have lot of documentation.But i can't get perfect solution for my client task.

Scenario: I have a client with many eBay store. On their eBay Auction template tool need to populate dynamic category with specified store id list on the template.

I've been searching for a couple days now, and I'm still a bit unsure about the best way to proceed.

How they create this app : http://apps.kernelbd.com/ebay/dynamic-shop-categories-v2/.
Is through eBay API ?

Please guide any geeks step by step

Have any free or purchase source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like your example application is using the "GetStore" call within the Trading API.

i have build you an example here: https://ebay-sdk.intradesys.com/s/66f041e16a60928b05a7e228a89c3799

this call returns all store categories for the given user ID, here a short example regarding to the store i used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <soapenv:Body>
  <GetStoreResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
   <Timestamp>2014-12-09T15:08:29.712Z</Timestamp>
   <Ack>Success</Ack>
   <Version>899</Version>
   <Build>E899_UNI_API5_17277987_R1</Build>
   <Store>
    <Name>de-lights4fun</Name>
    <SubscriptionLevel>Featured</SubscriptionLevel>
    <CustomCategories>
     <CustomCategory>
      <CategoryID>1</CategoryID>
      <Name>Other</Name>
      <Order>0</Order>
     </CustomCategory>
     <CustomCategory>
      <CategoryID>2405640016</CategoryID>
      <Name>Solar LED Beleuchtung</Name>
      <Order>1</Order>
      <ChildCategory>
       <CategoryID>2405649016</CategoryID>
       <Name>Solar LED Lichterkette</Name>
       <Order>1</Order>
      </ChildCategory>
      <ChildCategory>
       <CategoryID>2405650016</CategoryID>
       <Name>Solar LED Pflasterstein</Name>
       <Order>2</Order>
      </ChildCategory>
      <ChildCategory>
       <CategoryID>2405651016</CategoryID>
       <Name>Solar LED Lichternetz</Name>
       <Order>3</Order>
      </ChildCategory>
      <ChildCategory>
       <CategoryID>3094933016</CategoryID>
       <Name>Solar LED Laterne</Name>
       <Order>4</Order>
      </ChildCategory>
.....
```

this is similar to the page output you posted for the user "lights4fun-de"

php example could look like this if you are using the intradesys ebay sdk

```
require_once 'EbatNs_Session.php';
require_once 'EbatNs_Logger.php';
require_once 'EbatNs_ServiceProxy.php';
require_once 'EbatNs_Session.php';
require_once 'EbatNs_DataConverter.php';

$session = new EbatNs_Session();
$session->setSiteId(0);
$session->setUseHttpCompression(1);
$session->setAppMode(0);
$session->setDevId(YOUR_DEV_ID_HERE);
$session->setAppId(YOUR_APP_ID_HERE);
$session->setCertId(YOUR_CERT_ID_HERE);
$session->setRequestToken(YOUR_TOKEN_HERE);
$session->setTokenUsePickupFile(false);
$session->setTokenMode(true);

require_once 'EbatNs_ServiceProxy.php';
$proxy = new EbatNs_ServiceProxy($session, 'EbatNs_DataConverterUtf8');

require_once 'GetStoreRequestType.php';
$getstorerequest = new GetStoreRequestType();
$getstorerequest->setCategoryStructureOnly("true");
$getstorerequest->setUserID("lights4fun-de");
$getstorerequest->setVersion("899");

response = $proxy->GetStore($getstorerequest);
```

ebay docs to the call itself can be found here: http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/GetStore.html